# Need Help Identifying Screen Clip

Tags: windows, screens

we just purchased and moved into a home that as built in 1998. We can't find any paperwork or information about the windows that are installed (one contractor told us he suspected they were Anderson, but I have my doubts).

All we'd like to do is be able to open the windows for fresh air, but many of the screen clips are broken. I've been hunting for a while, but I can't seem to find what kind they are. What's more, they seem like they are attached to the screen itself, so if they're broken off, I'm not sure they can even be replaced.

Does anyone recognize what these kind of clips might be, or know if there's some kind of universal clip that might work instead?

[image: A working screen clip]
[image: A broken screen clip]

Comment: That appears to be a terrible design depending on a plastic clearly subject to UV embrittlement in an essentially exterior application. New clips appaer to go into the spline channel with the screen.

Comment: Try removing a clip and take it to you local hardware store.  Not a bigbox store.  The local hardware places often have the odd things that are common for homes built in their area.  Ask someone there for help.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be tempted to get some metal strapping and bend my own.  Might rust so use stainless.  Heck, even stainless or aluminum wire with some hooks bent into the ends might work.